# Dialog aparece somente depois que foi chamado

Tags: android, dialog, intent

Olá!

Em minha aplicação, tenho um `Button`, que ao ser clicado, abre a câmera do dispositivo para o usuário poder tirar uma foto:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //dialog da minha aplicação
    final ProgressDialog dialog = MobileUtils.getBasicProgressDialog(getBaseContext());

    // Cria uma intent para capturar uma imagem e retorna o controle para quem o chamou 
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ...
}
```

A aplicação deveria mostrar um `Dialog` antes de ir para a câmera, mas ela fica uns 5 segundos parada, abre a câmera, e o dialog só é mostrado na volta.
Existe uma maneira de só abrir a câmera APÓS o `Dialog` aparecer?

Comment: A única hipótese que vejo é a câmara ser chamada pelo/no *Dialog*.

Comment: vou estudar como fazer, postarei a resposta quando conseguir!

Comment: Talvez se você mudar a sua abordagem e analisar o contexto seja a melhor opção. O usuário clicou em um botão de tirar foto e você quer mostrar um alerta antes dele abrir a camera. Não faz mais sentido você exibir o dialog com um botão "Entendi" e, ao clicar neste botão, abrir a camera? Ou ainda, não seria melhor extrair esta informação para outra parte do layout, que não requer um dialog?

Comment: Na verdade o dialog apenas exibe um "aguarde", e seria apenas para orientar o usuário que a câmera vai abrir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isto vai chamar a camera após 15 segundos:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Isto será chamdo após 15 segundos...
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
};
new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
```

Comment: Quem irá utilizar uma aplicação que demora 15 segundos para abrir a câmara.

Comment: @ramaral, trata-se apenas de um exemplo, para ele ter noção do funcionamento!

Comment: realmente, aqui funciona até com delay de 1 segundo, mas acho meio incerto que vá funcionar sempre deixando um delay pequeno

Comment: Caso tenha dúvida, segue a documentação: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Por enquanto estou usando essa abordagem, aparentemente um delay pequeno já basta pra ele abrir o dialog primeiro, obrigado!